# ListView doesn't scroll to end, when keyboard using

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My ListView should automatically scroll to end, when new message received or sent. 
But when I use Android keyboard to send message from EditText below ListView, ListView resized and new message, which I want to send, appears out of screen and I have to scroll down to see it, even if keyboard disappears and ListView resizes again.

To scroll ListView I use:

```
listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(listView.getCount());
        }
    }, 100);
```

but is not working correctly in my case.

Does anyone know why it may occur? Is there a way, which ALWAYS scroll ListView to end?

Thanks, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: How did you get the event of showing the keyboard when you go to the EditText?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to add this line of code after you set selection to your list:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(listView.getCount());
```

Resulting code should look like this:

```
listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(listView.getCount());
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(listView.getCount());
        }
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this insead of your code:

```
listView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
```

(or set it by XML layout).

Answer (score 1):

Set android:windowSoftInputMode in manifest for the activity to `adjustPan|adjustResize`.

Comment: It is not working. I don't want to fix activity, because I have another elements in screen, for example left panel. This problem is only for ListView. I want to use method, which always scroll ListView to end.

Comment: The docs specifically say that this is not possible - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE