# Show only on item in Listview

Tags: android, listview

Android List view show only one item when i am using scroll view on the List view I want to scroll `listview` when keyboard appears. So i am using Scroll view But it's show only one Item-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/header" >
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cat1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:text="CAT1"
        android:textColor="#0C090A" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cat2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:text="CAT2"
        android:textColor="#0C090A" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cat3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:text="CAT3"
        android:textColor="#0C090A" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cat4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:text="CAT4"
        android:textColor="#0C090A" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cat5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:text="CAT5"
        android:textColor="#0C090A" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:text="@string/serach"
    android:textColor="#0C090A"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/createSearch"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:ems="5"
    android:singleLine="true" >
</EditText>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/review"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:text="@string/ReviewItem"
    android:textColor="#0C090A" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/review"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Item Code"
        android:textColor="#0C090A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtItemcode"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textColor="#0C090A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItem1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dip"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textColor="#0C090A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sentchallan"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
    android:text="                          Please send the Challan first"
    android:textColor="#98AFC7"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollprofile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lastbutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/createlist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:divider="#eeeeee"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:transcriptMode="normal" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lastbutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chReprocess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reprocess"
        android:textColor="#0C090A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createsavedraft"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:text="  Save Draft  "
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my main Screen

[image]

**But when key board appear screen goes up**

[image]

**But i want to scroll listview when keyboard appear**

Please Suggest me how can show all item in listview

Thanks In Advance

Comment: listview doesnt require a scroll...its auto

Comment: but it's not scroll when keyboard appear ,so i am using scroll view for that

Comment: What about [this](http://pastie.org/9528789)

Comment: u need to give height of list view,

Comment: @Priyanka you remove scroll view ' it's showed all item, But i want to set auto scroll when keyboard appear , s i am using scroll view.  Priyanka You know any way to set auto scroll listview when keyborad appear

Comment: Can you put any screenshot for what type of scenario you want..

Comment: It may be help you..See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12091654/1333022)

Comment: @Priyanka Please see updated question , i uploaded screen shots

Comment: Ok.. for this in menifest add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** in particular activity like this- 
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
For more See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4208067/1333022) also

Comment: @Priyanka i already used this  but did not work

Answer (score 0):

In menifest add `android:windowSoftInputMode` in particular activity like this-

```
<activity ... 

  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Or

```
<activity ... 

  android:windowSoftInputMode="">
</activity>
```

one of both options will work.
Happy Coding :)